# How to give a user the privilege to create symbolic links through C# or commandline?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, cmd

I have a program I built in C# using WPF. It is reliant on the user having the ability to create symbolic links. After trying my software on a test machine I discovered normal users don't have this privilege by default.

```
Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Create symbolic links
```

The first run of the program requires it to be run as admin for setup but all subsequent runs it shouldn't need to be. During this first run I need to give the user this privilege. Can this be done from C# or can I launch a cmd or powershell process to do this?

I tried:

```
Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "secedit /export /cfg c:\\secpol.cfg; (gc C:\\secpol.cfg).replace(\"SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege = \", \"SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege = " + Environment.UserName +",\") | Out-File C:\\secpol.cfg; secedit /configure /db c:\\windows\\security\\local.sdb /cfg c:\\secpol.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY; rm -force c:\\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 30 -c \"To use this program your computer must be restarted...\"");
```

The commands run successfully in PowerShell but after a reboot the Local Policy remains unchanged. Checking the log revealed that the registry values in secpol.cfg had applied successfully. I'm wondering if secedit can't change the policy I need to change since it doesn't have a registry key associated with it. I'd like to resolve this so I don't have to ask the user to manually change the setting. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using secedit, and thus this is not a PowerShell code issue. This is a Windows OS issue. You can easily set a logon script to make whatever change you without interaction from the user. If this is not a non-AD machine, then you could have domain-level enforcement going on here, overriding anything you'd set. If your setting is per instance, you should expect a reset on flush/reboots.

Comment: Your application should not forcefully override any user rights. That's very bad practice. If the user has too restricted rights, then he or his admin must elevate his rights accordingly - and explicitly. We should always strive to write software responsibly. Don't start to hack to breach security policies just for the sake to add more comfort (as you believe).

Comment: @BionicCode I don't mind informing the user that this must be done in order for the software to function however I'd still like to automate the process due to the fact that most users of the software aren't going to be power users that know how to do this. Additionally secpol.msc isn't included in Windows 10/11 Home editions which makes doing this even more difficult for the average user. It's funny that if I wanted to, Windows makes it easy for me to just make the current user become an admin on first install however this would be much more dangerous than just setting the one policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two things I had to fix above.

The first is an issue escaping the double quotes in the powershell argument. To solve that I just changed them to single quotes.

The second issue is that I was using `/areas SECURITYPOLICY` when SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege was actually in `/areas USER_RIGHTS`. Because we are just importing a configuration file created on the same system from moments ago I figure it's not necessary to use `/areas` at all so I just removed it.

The final code is:

```
// Allow user to create symbolic links
Process process = new Process();
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "secedit /export /cfg c:\\secpol.cfg; (gc C:\\secpol.cfg).replace('SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege = ', 'SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege = " + Environment.UserName + ",') | Out-File C:\\secpol.cfg; secedit /configure /db c:\\windows\\security\\local.sdb /cfg c:\\secpol.cfg; rm -force c:\\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false";
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 30 -c \"To use this program your computer must be restarted...\"");
```

Of course if you want to use this code for a production app you'll want to ask the user for permission before changing this setting as @BionicCode mentioned and you'll want to handle the reboot better.